# Path continuity of Time Inversion of a Brownian motion: proof doubt

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation, brownian-motion

Let $(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a Brownian motion. Define $X_t=tB_{1/t}$ if $t>0$ and $X_t=0$ if $t=0$.

In proving that $X$ is a Brownian motion, A. Klenke in Theorem 21.14 of his book Probability Theory (3rd version) checks for the **path continuity** that this term is bounded by zero:

$$
\limsup_{t\downarrow0} X_t = \limsup_{t\to\infty} \frac{1}{t}B_t\leq\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}B_n+\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sup\{B_t-B_n,t\in[n,n+1]\}
$$

He uses a SLLN argument for the first term in the RHS and a Borel Cantelli one for the second term to show that they tend to zero: this part is clear to me.

**He then concludes that $X$ is continuous at 0. Why is sufficient to check only the $\limsup_{t\downarrow0}X_t$?**

I would have checked that also this is bounded by zero with similar arguments:

$$
\liminf_{t\downarrow0} X_t = \limsup_{t\to\infty} \frac{1}{t}B_t\geq\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}B_n-\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sup\{B_n-B_t,t\in[n,n+1]\}
$$

**Why could we skip the "$\liminf$" argument?**

Please, let me know if something is not clear. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hint: use symmetry of Brownian motion

Comment: Basically the author skipped the part about the "liminf", without mentioning it, because it follows from the "limsup" part thanks to symmetry. Do I understand right your comment?Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's a very standard argument when dealing with Brownian motion. Maybe the author used it earlier and so felt it unnecessary to mention here?

Comment: Ok, thank you. Do you think I set up correctly the part about "liminf"?